# create windows or specific range and add value on specific column

Tags: python, r

I have a table like this:

```
position class supl score1 score2
1 3 2 15 18
2 2 5 18 13
3 4 5 13 18
4 6 9 15 12
. . . . .
. . . . .

100 5 9 12 09
```

I am trying to group on the basis of position 1-5 and subsequently adding score in the same window.
I tried to make the window but confused about how to add score in the same. I am trying to get output like:

```
position score1 score2
1-5 72 71
6-10 68 71
. . .
. . .
96-100 x x
```

How can I achieve my goal to cluster the data and cumulate the respective score. Please share your idea I will be grateful to you all.

Comment: will pandas solution work for you?

Comment: yes. I tried using pandas but it adds all the score not in the desired range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way via `pd.cut` / `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.position ,bins=[i for i in range(0, df.position.max() + 1, 5)])).agg({'score1': sum , 'score2': sum}).reset_index()
```

Alternative - (If you've all positions in order):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.position // 5).agg({'score1': sum , 'score2': sum}).reset_index()
df1.position = df1.position.astype(str) + '-' + df1.position.add(4).astype(str)
```